# OBJ-C: NSStrings - stringByAppendingString method

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring

Why does this syntax work

```
   NSString* newDisplayText = [currentDisplayText stringByAppendingString:digit];
```

while this one, (assigning the digit NSStrin to the new string first, and then sending it a message using the stringByAppendingString method). Does not work?

```
  NSString* newDisplayText = digit;
  [newDisplayText stringByAppendingString:currentDisplayText];
```

does sending it this method override it´s previous value I set?

Comment: What are the results of each? Where do you get `digit` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a really hard time figuring out exactly what you're asking, but here's a try:

The method `-stringByAppendingString:` does not modify its receiver. It constructs a new `NSString*` object and returns that. So saying

```
[newDisplayText stringByAppendingString:currentDisplayText];
```

does absolutely nothing, since you're throwing away the newly-created string.

Answer (score 2):

`stringByAppendingString:` returns an `NSString` object. It does not modify the receiver because `NSString` is immutable.

In your case, you need to assign the result of `stringByAppendingString` to `newDisplayText`.

```
NSString* newDisplayText = digit;
newDisplayText = [newDisplayText stringByAppendingString:currentDisplayText];
```